# mysql query results sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I am calling the results form a query to a list on my site based on if the item is "downtown_hosted". This works fine but I would now like to sort that list DESC, but can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Below is what I have:

```
$result_events = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events 
                                WHERE downtown='downtown_hosted'
                                ORDER BY date DESC
                                LIMIT 5 ");
```

Comment: And the error/what goes wrong?

Comment: The issue is that events don't display when I have the "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5" in select from. If I remove this call the items display but out of the desired DESC order.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the word "date" with backticks.

E.g.:

```
$result_events = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM events
    WHERE downtown='downtown_hosted'
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT 5
");
```

In practice it's not a bad habit to get into always enclosing your columns with backticks, so you will not have to worry about conflicting with language keywords.

Comment: @Salil - backticks are optional, but not when your column shares its name with a language keyword.

Comment: In practice it's not a bad habit to try to use ANSI SQL as much as possible and to avoid keywords as column names :)

Comment: If I remove the "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5" the items will display in the list but they are out of order. So the issue maybe with my list. The code I have for my list is: 

<? $i = 0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_events)) {
    if(strtotime($row['end_date']) > date('U') && $i < 6) {
  $i++;
  $title = $row['title'];
  $id = $row['id'];
  ?>
         
        <table> 
         <tr>
        <td align="center" <? if($i % 2){ ?> bgcolor="#DAE8F7"<? } ?>><span class=" newsLINK"><a href="events.php#<?=$id?>"><?=$title?></a></span></td>
         </tr>
       <? } 
  }
  ?>
</table>

Answer (score 6):

`date` is an SQL keyword. You can have a column called `date`, but every time you refer to it you will have to use identifier quotes. In MySQL this is accomplished using backticks: `` `date` ``